# how to set datasource incremental refresh on tableau server?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau.

I published MySQL datasource on my tableau server.
And I changed the datasource to extract mode on my tableau web site.
But I can't set the incremental refresh, just only full refresh.

On the other hand in my desktop tableau, I can set the incremental refresh.
But it may affects on extracted data in my local pc.

How to set incremental refresh in my tableau server datasource?

I couldn't find about this in tableau manual site.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Tableau Desktop you have to set your dataset in extract mode, selecting the incremental refresh (with a specific column to be considered as reference, such as ID or date).

Once you're done, you can publish that datasource in order to let Tableau server know how you want to handle data.

Basically, the first thing you need to do is setting the datasource and evaluate if you want to publish it on server (so other workbook can connect to it) or just publish that datasource "inside" a specific workbook.

Comment: thanks, I want to publish the datasource on server. (not only inside a workbook)
So in my tableau desktop, i set the one datasource to incremental extract and publish on server. 
And I checked the status on tableau server site, the published datasource is live. And I just only change it to full refresh.
But If I publish workbook, the included datasource can be incremental refresh.

Comment: I'm not sure to get your point... published datasources can live their own life on tableau server even though any dashboard is based on them. I don't understand the poing of publishing an incremental datasource and the switching it to full refresh: mayb I'm missing something or your primary goal.

Comment: Sorry for confusing, my point is "How to make published datasource (not inside workbook) with incremental refresh?", but I could only make it with full refresh.

Comment: In Tableau Desktop you have to set up your datasoruce in order to work in extract mode and in the specifc form you have to select incremental refresh (based on a specific column); then you just need to publish that datasource on Tableau server... please see the related documentation: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_refresh.htm

Comment: I found that it is impossible to set incremental refresh on tableau web.

https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/datasource_extract.htm

Comment: it's actually written here : https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/schedule_add.htm "Incremental refresh is available only if you configured for it in Tableau Desktop before publishing the extract"